# Issue using Ghost with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, knex.js, ghost

I'm following the instructions [here](https://docs.ghost.org/docs/using-ghost-as-an-npm-module) to use Ghost as an NPM module, and attempting to setup Ghost for production.

I'm running Google cloud sql proxy locally. When I run `NODE_ENV=production knex-migrator init --mgpath node_modules/ghost` I get this error message:

```
NAME: RollbackError
CODE: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR
MESSAGE: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~[SOME_IP_ADDRESS]' (using password: NO)
```

Running `knex-migrator init --mgpath node_modules/ghost` works just fine, and I can launch the app locally with no problems. It's only the I try to setup the app for production that I get problems.

EDIT: I can connect to the db via MySQL Workbench, using the same credentials I'm using in the config below

Here's my `config.production.json` (with private data removed):

```
{
    "production": {
        "url": "https://MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
        "fileStorage": false,
        "mail": {},
        "database": {
            "client": "mysql",
            "connection": {
                "socketPath": "/cloudsql/MY_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME",
                "user": "USER",
                "password": "PASSWORD",
                "database": "DATABASE_NAME",
                "charset": "utf8"
            },
            "debug": false
        },
        "server": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": "2368"
        },
        "paths": {
            "contentPath": "content/"
        }
    }
}
```

And `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
env_variables:
  MYSQL_USER: ******
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ******
  # e.g. my-awesome-project:us-central1:my-cloud-sql-instance-name
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: ******
beta_settings:
  # The connection name of your instance on its Overview page in the Google
  # Cloud Platform Console, or use `YOUR_PROJECT_ID:YOUR_REGION:YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME`
  cloud_sql_instances: ******

# Setting to keep gcloud from uploading not required files for deployment
skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
  - ^(.*/)?.*~$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
  - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
  - ^(.*/)?\..*$
  - ^(.*/)?.*\.ts$
  - ^(.*/)?config\.development\.json$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

My config file shouldn't have the "production" property. My config should look like this:

```
{
        "url": "https://MY_PROJECT_ID.appspot.com",
        "fileStorage": false,
        "mail": {},
        "database": {
            "client": "mysql",
            "connection": {
                "socketPath": "/cloudsql/MY_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME",
                "user": "USER",
                "password": "PASSWORD",
                "database": "DATABASE_NAME",
                "charset": "utf8"
            },
            "debug": false
        },
        "server": {
            "host": "0.0.0.0",
            "port": "8080"
        },
        "paths": {
            "contentPath": "content/"
        }
}
```

It now overrides the default config.

The only issue is that you can't use knex-migrator with the "socketPath" property set, but this is needed to run the app in the cloud.

Comment: My answer to your question included the correct structure for your config. FYI I've been trialling out the idea of us (Ghost) switching our standard community support from using slack to stackoverflow. 
The community here seems to be very hostile and helping people here is a horrible experience.

Comment: @ErisDS, thanks for your help, and sorry you feel that way. I wasn't intending to come across as hostile, just trying to be objective in my comments. I provided a separate answer to make it clear to anyone coming to the page exactly how the issue was solved, and the associated caveat.

Comment: @HNipps what does your "start" : "node index.js" script line look like?  I am running into the same error and seem to have come to an impass.

Comment: Are you saying your config is config.json and not config.production.json?

Comment: Additionally, I am getting either Bad gateway errors or Cannot Get / errors

Comment: @AlexanderN. in package.json I have - "start": "node index.js". The file should still be called "config.production.json", and should be in the root of your project.

Comment: @AlexanderN. what's the exact error message you get? Do you have cloud_sql_proxy running locally?

Comment: I actually got all this sorted and ran into a different defect for using Google cloud storage. Thanks for your commitment to help though. I had followed some outdated instructions and got myself confused

Answer (score 0):

The file `ghost.prod.config.js` isn't something Ghost recognises - I'm not sure where that file name came from, but Ghost < 1.0 used `config.js` with all environments in one file, and Ghost >= 1.0 uses `config.<env>.json` with each environment in its own file.

Your `config.production.json` file doesn't contain your MySQL connection info, and therefore the knex-migrator tool is not able to connect to your DB.

If you merge the contents of `ghost.prod.config.js` into `config.producton.json` this should work fine.

Your config.production.json should look something like this:

```
 {
     "url": "https://something.appspot.com",
     "database": {
         "client": "mysql",
         "connection": {
             "socketPath": "path",
             "user": "user",
             "password": "password",
             "database": "dbname",
             "charset": "utf8"
        }        
    }
}
```

The caveat here is that the new JSON format cannot contain code or logic, only explicit values, e.g. `process.env.PORT || "2368"` is no longer permitted.

Instead, you'll need to use either arguments or environment variables to provide dynamic configuration. Documentation for how to use environment variables is here: https://docs.ghost.org/docs/config#section-running-ghost-with-config-env-variables

E.g. `NODE_ENV=production port=[your port] database__connection__user=[your user] ...etc... knex-migrator init --mgpath node_modules/ghost`

You'd need to add an environment variable for every dynamic variable in the config.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't help. I still get the same error message. Also, my config.development.json file is setup in exactly the same way (but pointing to ghost.dev.config.js) and it works just fine.

Comment: I understand your frustration, the development mode of Ghost has a full set of fallbacks, so it will work even if you don't provide config. However, if you are using Ghost 1.0 it will only look for files of the pattern config.<env>.json, the .js files will not be loaded.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example config.production.json. My suggestion would be to try it with explicit values to start with if possible, and one-by-one swap them for environment variables.

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same error. I've updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Where should my config.production.json file be? I've tried it inside the root folder of my project, as well as /node_modules/ghost/

Comment: At the root. Your file structure is expected to look like this: https://docs.ghost.org/docs/using-ghost-as-an-npm-module#section-full-file-tree

Comment: The config file is in the root of my project, so I tried to put it at the root of the Ghost package in node_modules, but it didn't make a difference.